# Can't open .jar files, "The java jar file cannot be launched."

Tags: macos

I can't open any .jar files. Java is up to date, the jar file is supposed to be executable, but I can't open it with Jar Launcher. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try to open them?

Comment: From what url did you install java. Have you tried running the jar from the command line?